# Dibujado de polylines en Google Maps Api

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Eh logrado hacer el trazo de rutas en el mapa, lo que quiero conseguir es que la unión entre las polylines sea redondeada, o que no haya cortes bruscos entre trazos.

Trazo logrado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trazo al cual se desea llegar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void onDrawRoutes(final GoogleMap mMap) throws JSONException {

    final JSONArray polyline = mArray.getJSONObject(mRoute).getJSONArray("legs").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < polyline.length(); i ++) {
                String points = null;
                try {
                    points = polyline.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                lists.add(i, PolyUtil.decode(points));
            }
            return null;
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lists.size(); j++) {
                List<LatLng> iterable = lists.get(j);
                mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .addAll(iterable)
                        .width(20)
                        .color(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.ligthBlue, null)).geodesic(true));
            }
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

Comment: Interesante Jorge, la API según recuerdo no puede redondear, únicamente si es una trayectoria continua!.

Comment: @Elenasys Hay alguna forma de dibujarla tu mismo?

Comment: Mi comentario era acerca de que sabía no se podia realizar pero necesito investigar si actualmente se puede realizar, sería interesante, lo que he hecho son unicamente trayectorias continuas y de esta forma siempre se muestra redonda la linea al ser curva.

Comment: Intentaste dibujarlas en una unica polyline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que estas queriendo lograr con las [polylíneas](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines) lo que hacen las [direcciones](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start).

Si es obligatorio que uses polylíneas, intenta reducir el ancho de la misma, o bien en "las esquinas", usa varias líneas para "suavizar" el ángulo entre una y otra. La forma más simple de implementar esto es por medio de una [ochava](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chafl%C3%A1n_(arquitectura))

Comment: Estoy implementando la API de direcciones para obtener las rutas entre dos puntos, supongo que hay que utilizar polylineas, o por lo menos eh visto que lo utilizan para estos casos. Lo que estoy viendo es el tema de la ochava, ya que dibujo las rutas que me devuelve el servicio y no sabría como darme cuenta cuando estoy en una esquina.

Comment: El propósito de las polylíneas es dibujar líneas, y si ves las rutas como líneas podría tener sentido, pero para las rutas entiendo que está la [API de direcciones](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start). Me parece que deberías informarte más acerca de [esta](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start). ¿Has oído del Problema XY?

Comment: No no, de que se trata?, volveré a leer la documentación de la API.

Comment: Es acerca de preguntar como usar una "solución X", en este caso las polylíneas, para resolver un "problema Y", en este caso, dibujar rutas. Esto es un problema porque existe el riesgo de tener conversaciones muy largas e "improductivas" sobre la "solución X" cuando esta no solucionará el "problema Y". En [meta.se] está [What is the Problem XY?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Desconozco si hay algo similar en español.

Comment: Claro que puedo estar equivocado. Recién se me ocurrió buscar [google maps api smooth polyline](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=google+maps+api+smooth+polyline). Hay muchos resultados, varios de [so].

Comment: Claro, en esos resultados me base para llegar a lo que tengo hoy, pero tenes mucha razón también en lo que decís. Seguiré buscando.